# Python counting event occurrences from two int arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two different int arrays that each correspond to events in time. For instance, if the time limit was set to 10 minutes, they would look like this:

```
array1[1.1, 2.4, 4.5, 6.5, 9.0]
array2[1.2, 3.1, 4.4, 5.9, 7.2, 8.6, 9.7]
```

I want to create a for loop that simulates this time, and counts the events that happen for each array, but I need to have both arrays be counted at the same time.

```
start_time = 0
array1_events = 0
array2_events = 0
for start_time in range(10): #simulate counting to 10 minutes
   #count event occurrences in the arrays
```

This is how I want the program to behave:

```
array1_events += 1 #array1[1.1]
array2_events += 1 #array2[1.2]
array1_events += 1 #array1[2.4]
array2_events += 1 #array2[3.1]
array2_events += 1 #array1[4.4]
array1_events += 1 #array1[4.5]
array2_events += 1 #array2[5.9]
array1_events += 1 #array1[6.5]
array2_events += 1 #array2[7.2]
array2_events += 1 #array2[8.6]
array1_events += 1 #array1[9.0]
array2_events += 1 #array2[9.7]
```

How can I accomplish this in my for loop?

This is how I am generating each array:

```
import numpy as np
alpha = 0.2
tMax = 8000
k = np.random.poisson((1-alpha)/10*tMax, 1)
arrivals = sorted( np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=tMax, size=k) )
```

Comment: You want `numpy` arrays or simple lists? Also, are those values in the arrays fixed? Or how are they generated?

Comment: Does adding these two lines `array1_events = len(array1)` and `array2_events = len(array2)` to your `for` loop solve your problem?

Comment: @Gabriel
I'll put how I am generating each array at the end of my original question

Comment: If you are stepping through in 1 minute intervals, do you only want to count events that happen within that time interval during that iteration of the loop? It seems that the details of how you want the simulation to run are important to how you will be counting the events. Can you explain more, or provide the code in the loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution would be to merge your arrays while keeping info about which value belongs to which array:

```
array1 = [1.1, 2.4, 4.5, 6.5, 9.0]
array2 = [1.2, 3.1, 4.4, 5.9, 7.2, 8.6, 9.7]

merged_array = [(i, 1) for i in array1] + [(i, 2) for i in array2]
merged_array.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])

event_1 = 0
event_2 = 0
for i in merged_array:
    event_1 += 1 if i[1] == 1 else 0
    event_2 += 1 if i[1] == 2 else 0
```

Since the array is sorted, all the values are retrieved in temporal order. Moreover, since each value carries the array it belonged to, it is possible to update the `event`s variables.

Answer (score 0):

If you count both separately, you may count same values twice. So you need to subtract same values from the result. You can use `set` to get unique values. After getting unique values, you can subtract it from total to see how many elements counted twice.

arr1 = [1.1, 2.4, 4.5, 6.5, 9.0]
arr2 = [1.2, 3.1, 4.4, 5.9, 7.2, 8.6, 9.7]

```
arr1_count = len(arr1)
arr2_count = len(arr2)
arr1.extend(arr2)
both_count = len(set(arr1))

counted_twice = arr1_count + arr2_count - both_count

count = arr1_count + arr2_count - 0.5 * counted_twice  # this is what you are looking for.
print(count)
```

Comment: Hello, does this code work for you? I get a syntax error when I try to run it.